# Let be $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ the linear transformation define by $f(x, y)=(2 x+y, x+3 y) .$ Find $f(D)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let be $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ the linear transformation define by $f(x, y)=(2 x+y, x+3 y) .$ Find $f(D)$ such that :

$D= $ The triangle with vertices $(-1,3),(2,1),(3,-2)$

I find D= $(\frac{-6}{5},\frac{7}{5}),(1,0)$ and $(\frac{11}{5},\frac{-7}{5})$ Is this right?

Im just doing for example for the first point $2x+y=1$ and $x+3y=3$ and the I solve is right?

Comment: Either you are misunderstand the question or you are writing the question incorrectly. If $D$ is the triangle with vertices $(-1,3), (2,1), (3,-2)$, then $f(D)$ is the image of the triangle. From the work you've attempted, it seems like you are trying to find $D$, given $f(D)$.

Comment: Ohhh Now I see, the I just have to apply the linear transformation to every point of D right? I mean $f(-1,3), f(2,1) and f(3,2)$ right?

Comment: If the question is how it is written, then yes. See my answer below. If you wrote the problem incorrectly, that is not something I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Take two points, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. The line connecting them can be written as $L(t)=t(x_1,y_1)+(1-t)(x_2,y_2)$. If $f(x,y)$ is linear, then $f(L(t))=tf(x_1,y_1)+(1-t)f(x_2,y_2)$, which is a line connecting $f(x_1,y_1)$ to $f(x_2,y_2)$. It should be easy to see that $f$ will map the triangle to another triangle.